# Add list of figures and list of tables at the end of the document

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to add  the list of tables and figures at the end of the document. How is this possible ?

Comment: How about putting `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` right before `\end{document}`?

Comment: If that doesn't help, please elaborate and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @Skillmon: A revolutionary idea, putting `\listof... ` at the end of the document ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean more than one copy, you can use a savebox.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\lof}
\begin{document}
\setbox\lof=\vbox{\listoffigures}
\usebox\lof
\newpage

\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\usebox\lof
\end{document}
```

Comment: If it is more than one page, you can use \copybox and \unvbox.